# Stop responsive background-image from reducing at certain point

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a background-image which I made responsive by adding `background-size: 80%;` to my CSS code. When I minimise the browser window it works to a certain extent, the thing is: I want the background-image to stop reducing at a certain point, as the other elements on my site do. But it reduces infinitely. To illustrate what I mean, check it up on my website: http://www.filmfutter.com/forum/
It's the white image at the top.

Currently the CSS code looks like that:

```
background-image: url(../images/blueTemptation/blueTemptationHeader.png); 
background-size: 80%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: top center;
```

Comment: I would investigate the usage of media-queries in your CSS to change the applied style when the window shrinks to a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

You might add a media query breakpoint at that specific point. The given pixel value are approximate.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
  body {
    background-size: 897px; 
  }

}
```